# Angular JS, ngRoute isn't working

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've been working on my ngRoute without sucess. I can't load the module 'ngRoute'. I don't know why. When I try this code, nothing happens, just a blank page.

Here is my app.js .

```
var app = angular.module('tutorialApp', ['ngRoute', 'tutorialCtrlModule']);

app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider

        .when("/", {
            templateUrl : "views/viewCourse.html"
            controllers : "tutorialCtrl"
        });
});
```

My index.html:

```
<html ng-app="tutorialApp">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

    <title>Teste</title>
    <meta name="description" content="The HTML5 Herald">
    <meta name="author" content="SitePoint">

    <script src="lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular-locale-pt-br.js"></script>
    <script src="lib/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controllers/tutorialCtrl.js"></script>



    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
</head>
<body>

<div ng-view></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: load `angular.js` before any modules. What does error in console tell you?

Comment: Cannot resolve directory 'lib'
Cannot resolve directory 'lib'
Cannot resolve file 'angular.min.js'
Cannot resolve directory 'js'
Cannot resolve file 'app.js'
Cannot resolve directory 'js'
Cannot resolve directory 'controllers'
Cannot resolve file 'tutorialCtrl.js'
Cannot resolve directory 'js'
Cannot resolve file 'angular-locale-pt-br.js'
Cannot resolve directory 'js'
Cannot resolve file 'angular-route.min.js.js'

Comment: Those are not browser console errors. Where are they coming from? Sounds like server side problem and your paths are clarly incorrect

Comment: No... Is it a console error from WebStorm, sorry. Nothing happens from browser, just an empty page.

Comment: what are the errors your are getting in the console ? what url did you try ?

Answer (score 0):

Two Things:

1. Load angular-route.js after loading Angular.js
2. there is a syntax Error while defining the route in app.js; as there should be a comma ',' after 'templateUrl' value.
   It should look like this:

.when("/", {
            templateUrl : "views/viewCourse.html",
            controllers : "tutorialCtrl"
        });

Also do you mind sharing the URL while accessing this page in your the browser.

I have created a simple Plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/tBisV2hhmJbHOyYAPPhn

```
angular.module("myApp", ['ngRoute']);
angular.module("myApp").config(function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/test', {
      templateUrl: 'Welcome.html',
      controller: 'TestController',
      controllerAs: 'testController'
    })
});

angular.module("myApp").controller('testCtrl', testCtrl);

function testCtrl($timeout, $q, $log, $location, $scope) {

  $scope.navigate = function(){
    $log.info('Success');
    $location.path('/test');
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes @Harsh, it's working, but not totally. The server is in localhost. 

I changed script src to this:

   __<script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="//code.angularjs.org/1.6.2/i18n/angular-locale_pt-br.js"></script>__

and then start to work, I think I got some problems with the ngRoute for localhost. He can identify the url path.

Comment: What does browser debugger say?